# adding a textbox to the right corner of the existing pdf using ITextSharp in C#

Tags: itext, sharp

I tiied to add a TextBox to the right corner of the existing pdf using c#, but im unable to get it done. I have wrote the following code,but it is not helping in solving the problem, can any body please suggest me

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);               
        PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        Document doc = new Document();

        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
        {
            PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);


            //PdfContentByte cb = null;
            //PdfImportedPage page;
            int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;                    
            for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
            {
                var size1 = reader.GetPageSize(i);
                w = size1.Width;
                h = size1.Height;
                stamper.FormFlattening = true;

                TextField tf = new TextField(stamper.Writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 100), displaytext);
                //Change the orientation of the text
                tf.Rotation = 0;
                stamper.AddAnnotation(tf.GetTextField(), i);
            }
        }
        bytes = stream.ToArray();
}
File.WriteAllBytes(str, bytes);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "TextBox"? Do you mean a multiline text field? A free text annotation? Actual page content?

Comment: Actually it is a string that I want to display(want to add extra line into the page content),when I try to use the below code it is just displaying but it is not erasing the below text

Comment: ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_BASELINE, new Paragraph(displaytext.ToString(), blackFont), 250f, 5f, 0);

Comment: *"it is just displaying but it is not erasing the below text"* - Well, yes, obviously no text will be erased, after all you do nothing to cause some text to be erased. Is the text you want to be erased part of the page content? Then you can either cover it with a filled Rectangle or actually remove it using the iText redaction classes (`PdfCleanUp*` in itext-xtra). Or is the text top remove in some annotation? Then you have to update the annotations accordingly.

Comment: hi,nice to hear back, I tried the exact way of adding a Rectangle and doing it,but also im unable to get the code as I have tried in the top.any suggestions with the code,

Comment: Is the text you want to be erased part of the page content? Or is the text to remove in some annotation?

Comment: to be erased part of the page content

Comment: And do you want to add the text by means of an annotation as in your question? Or by means of page content as in one of your comments here?

Comment: I want to add the text as a page content in the right bottom corner of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As the OP clarified in comments to the question, he wants*

- *to add the text as a page content in the right bottom corner of the page and*
- *the page content previously existing there to be removed.*

A simple implementation of this would include

- first covering the existing page content with a filled rectangle and
- then writing text there.

These tasks can be achieved with these helper methods:

```
void EmptyTextBoxSimple(PdfStamper stamper, int pageNumber, Rectangle boxArea, BaseColor fillColor)
{
    PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(pageNumber);
    canvas.SaveState();
    canvas.SetColorFill(fillColor);
    canvas.Rectangle(boxArea.Left, boxArea.Bottom, boxArea.Width, boxArea.Height);
    canvas.Fill();
    canvas.RestoreState();
}
```

and

```
ColumnText GenerateTextBox(PdfStamper stamper, int pageNumber, Rectangle boxArea)
{
    PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(pageNumber);
    ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(canvas);
    columnText.SetSimpleColumn(boxArea);
    return columnText;
}
```

E.g. like this:

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source))
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create)))
{
    Rectangle cropBox = reader.GetCropBox(1);
    Rectangle bottomRight = new Rectangle(cropBox.GetRight(216), cropBox.Bottom, cropBox.Right, cropBox.GetBottom(146));
    EmptyTextBoxSimple(stamper, 1, bottomRight, BaseColor.WHITE);
    ColumnText columnText = GenerateTextBox(stamper, 1, bottomRight);
    columnText.AddText(new Phrase("Some test text to draw into a text box in the lower right corner of the first page"));
    columnText.Go();
}
```

For this source page

[image: source page]

the sample code generates this

[image: result page]

#### Addendum

In a comment the OP indicated

> it is working for all files but for some pdf files it is displaying in the middle

Eventually he supplied a [sample file](https://github.com/kvsskk/kishorefiles/raw/master/0611022301_e%20(2).pdf) for which the issue occurs. And indeed, with this file the issue could be reproduced.

The cause for the issue is that the pages in the sample file use page rotation, something that iText (only) partially allows users to ignore. In particular iText automatically rotates text to be upright after rotation and transforms coordinates, but when retrieving the cropbox of a page, one still has to apply rotation before making use of it coordinates. Thus, a more complete example would be like this:

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source))
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create)))
{
    Rectangle cropBox = reader.GetCropBox(1);
    int rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(1);
    while (rotation > 0)
    {
        cropBox = cropBox.Rotate();
        rotation -= 90;
    }
    Rectangle bottomRight = new Rectangle(cropBox.GetRight(216), cropBox.Bottom, cropBox.Right, cropBox.GetBottom(146));
    EmptyTextBoxSimple(stamper, 1, bottomRight, BaseColor.WHITE);
    ColumnText columnText = GenerateTextBox(stamper, 1, bottomRight);
    columnText.AddText(new Phrase("Some test text to draw into a text box in the lower right corner of the first page"));
    columnText.Go();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it helped me a lot in solving this issue.

Comment: Great! In that case please accept the answer (click the tick at its upper left).

Comment: hi mkl,code worked and im facing issue with rectanglebox size reducing ,if im reducing the box size then the string is not displaying in the box ,I tried to reduce the size of the box to the right corner bottom of the page with minimum width and height where only box is displaying but text is not displaying,is there any way to reduce the box

Comment: As that happens when you reduce the box size, I assume that you make the box too small: Depending on its characteristics, a font might be larger (and require more height) than you'd expect looking at a specific output. As you did not provide your exact source and data, I can only assume, though.

Comment: hi mkl, I solved this, after some r and d on this issue I solved through reducing the height directly.

Comment: hi mkl,it is working for all files but for some pdf files it is displaying in the middle, I tired the logic canvas.Rectangle(boxArea.Left, boxArea.Bottom, boxArea.Width, boxArea.Height); as boxarea.right but it is not working,is there any dimensions for this

Comment: hi mkl, I think the problem is with iTextSharp.text.Rectangle bottomRight = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(cropBox.GetRight(199), cropBox.Bottom, cropBox.Right, cropBox.GetBottom(18));. even though I tried to place the box in right corner it is displaying in the middle.

Comment: hi mkl,nice to hear back,how to share a file can you give me your emailid

Comment: im unable to add complete logic in comments

Comment: i added it in github,please check the link

Comment: @SaiKishoreKumar If I understand your problem correctly, it is that the code *is working for all files but for some pdf files it is displaying in the middle*. As this behavior depends on the PDF in question, I need a sample PDF for which this undesired behavior occurs. Please share one such PDF.

Comment: hi mkl,thanks for the reply, I have kept the pdf document in the following url ,please check and for security reasons I have deleted the content,sorry for that but the bottom line is coming in the middle. the link is ,https://github.com/kvsskk/kishorefiles the filename is 0611022301_e (2).pdf

Comment: @SaiKishoreKumar The special thing about your PDF is that it uses page rotation. I extended my answer, cf. the Addendum, to consider it.

Comment: hi mkl,nice to hear back,and really appreciated for your work.

Comment: hi mkl, how can I collect the source from addendum is it a location or a person name

Comment: I don't understand that. I added an addendum to my answer, no specific source but me, myself, and I.

Comment: I do not know the addendum meaning ,sorry for that

Comment: An *addendum* merely is something *added*, like a *post scriptum*.